# Add images to website if they exist

Tags: javascript, image

I have a folder which contains some images:

```
image1-1.jpg
image1-2.jpg
image2-1.jpg
image2-2.jpg
image2-3.jpg
image2-4.jpg
image3-1.jpg
image3-2.jpg
```

and a series of links:

```
link 1
link 2
link 3
```

I want to use just JavaScript so that when a user clicks on one of these links the corresponding images will be loaded and inserted into my webpage. I have tried with a **for** loop but it always inserts the amount of images of the highest 'category' of images. For example I click link 1 but it inserts 4 images because image2 goes up to 4.

I've tried this:

```
var category = <somenumber>
var img = new Image();
for(var i=1;i<375/*the max is 374 images*/;i++){
  img.src = "image"+category+"-"+I+".jpg";
  if(img.width != 0){
    $('<img src="'+img.src+'" width="200">').appendTo('#imgbox');// I use jquery to
  }
}
```

PS: I'm trying not to use php or anything like that

Comment: Can you please show you have tried?

Comment: Tried `new Image().onload` ?

Comment: I tried but in the for loop the src changes before the image has loaded

Comment: It's a very bad idea to do this via javascript. In PHP, there's a `glob` function that suits your needs.

Comment: Generally you're now bombing your server with invalid requests. ike a bruteforce attack.

Comment: See if this can point you to the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/a/11144849/961695

Comment: Loading 300 images per script in one go is not a __brute force attack__ but something usual websites with lot of graphics do nowadays ...

Comment: The images are low sized. only a few kb's per image.

Comment: It is a brute force if you load 404 errors to find out what files exist and what do not. That's definition of brute force in fact - try/fail/repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the list of images, the names have the following scheme:

```
image<category>-<number>.jpg
```

Your `for` loop is generating images like

```
image<number>.jpg
```

How can this load any image? I assume, images like `image<number>.jpg` do actually exist, but as a side effect of the error, this is hiding the error.

Next: You create an image Object and within the loop you ar assigning a new src to this one image. Further, you are only using the URL of the image object, which already exists as string.
Two possibilities:

## 1) create an image object within the loop:

```
for(var i=1;i<375/*the max is 374 images*/;i++){
  var img = new Image();

  $( img ).load(function() {
     if(this.width != 0){
        $(this).appendTo('#imgbox');
     }
  });
  img.src = "image"+i+".jpg";
}
```

Have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/acRVX/1/)

## 2) Just use the url, no image object:

```
for(var i=1;i<375/*the max is 374 images*/;i++){
  
    $('<img src=image'+i+'.jpg width="200">').appendTo('#imgbox');
}
```

And at least you need to correct what I wrote above regarding names of the images.

Comment: The problem with this first option is that half of the images doesn't pop up because they are being checked before they have loaded. And the second one creates 374 img objects.